# Why using semaphores instead of condition variables hang sometimes in this problem?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore, condition-variable

I'm writing a code for an assignment for [an operating systems course](https://www.ops-class.org/).

[This](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/synchprobs/whalemating.c) is the file I'm editing.

[This](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/test/synchprobs.c) is the test code for the solution.

**Note**: looking at these files isn't necessary to understand the code.

The assignment asks for a way to communicate between threads. There are 3 types of threads: `male`, `female` and `matchmaker`.

I have 3 functions: `male(thread_id)`, `female(thread_id)` and `matchmaker(thread_id)`.

A `male`, `female` or a `matchmaker` thread should sleep until two threads of the other two types are available. for example a `male` thread should sleep if there is no a single `female` thread running or if there is not a single `matchmaker` thread running. If the three types are present, the `matchmaker` will match the `male` and the `female` threads and then the 3 threads should exit.

The test code creates 10 `male` threads, 10 `female` threads and 10 `matchmaker` threads and expects one of each type to communicate together then exits.

**Note**: the function code that handles each type of thread is almost identical.

I solved the problem using condition variables and it's working fine. Here is the solution:

```
struct lock *lock = NULL;

struct cv *male_cv = NULL;
struct cv *female_cv = NULL;
struct cv *matchmaker_cv = NULL;

int male_count = 0;
int female_count = 0;
int matchmaker_count = 0;

void whalemating_init() {
    lock = lock_create("whalemating lock");

    male_cv = cv_create("male");
    female_cv = cv_create("female");
    matchmaker_cv = cv_create("matchmaker");

    male_count = 0;
    female_count = 0;
    matchmaker_count = 0;
}

/*
 * Called by the driver during teardown.
 */

void
whalemating_cleanup() {

    lock_destroy(lock);
    lock = NULL;

    cv_destroy(male_cv);
    cv_destroy(female_cv);
    cv_destroy(matchmaker_cv);

    male_cv = NULL;
    female_cv = NULL;
    matchmaker_cv = NULL;
}

void
male(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling male_start and male_end when
     * appropriate.
     */

    male_start(index);

    lock_acquire(lock);
    
    if (matchmaker_count > 0 && female_count > 0) {
        cv_signal(matchmaker_cv, lock);
        cv_signal(female_cv, lock);
    } else {
        male_count++;
        cv_wait(male_cv, lock);
        male_count--;
    }
        
    lock_release(lock);

    male_end(index);    

    return;
}

void
female(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling female_start and female_end when
     * appropriate.
     */

    female_start(index);

    lock_acquire(lock);
    
    if (matchmaker_count > 0 && male_count > 0) {
        cv_signal(matchmaker_cv, lock);
        cv_signal(male_cv, lock);
    } else {
        female_count++;
        cv_wait(female_cv, lock);
        female_count--;
    }
        
    lock_release(lock);

    female_end(index);  

    return;
}

void
matchmaker(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling matchmaker_start and matchmaker_end
     * when appropriate.
     */

    matchmaker_start(index);
    
    lock_acquire(lock);
    
    if (male_count > 0 && female_count > 0) {
        cv_signal(male_cv, lock);
        cv_signal(female_cv, lock);
    } else {
        matchmaker_count++;
        cv_wait(matchmaker_cv, lock);
        matchmaker_count--;
    }
        
    lock_release(lock);

    matchmaker_end(index);  

    return;
}
```

And here is the one using semaphores that doesn't always work (works fine on some runs and hangs on ther runs):

```
struct semaphore *male_sem = NULL;
struct semaphore *female_sem = NULL;
struct semaphore *matchmaker_sem = NULL;

/*
 * Called by the driver during initialization.
 */

void whalemating_init() {
    // sem_create(sem_name, sem_initial_value);
    male_sem = sem_create("male", 0);
    female_sem = sem_create("female", 0);
    matchmaker_sem = sem_create("matchmaker", 0);
}

/*
 * Called by the driver during teardown.
 */

void
whalemating_cleanup() {
    sem_destroy(male_sem);
    sem_destroy(female_sem);
    sem_destroy(matchmaker_sem);

    male_sem = NULL;
    female_sem = NULL;
    matchmaker_sem = NULL;
}

void
male(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling male_start and male_end when
     * appropriate.
     */

    male_start(index);

    V(male_sem);
    V(male_sem);
    P(female_sem);
    P(matchmaker_sem);

    male_end(index);    

    return;
}

void
female(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling female_start and female_end when
     * appropriate.
     */

    female_start(index);
    
    V(female_sem);
    V(female_sem);
    P(male_sem);
    P(matchmaker_sem);

    female_end(index);  

    return;
}

void
matchmaker(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling matchmaker_start and matchmaker_end
     * when appropriate.
     */

    matchmaker_start(index);

    V(matchmaker_sem);
    V(matchmaker_sem);
    P(male_sem);
    P(female_sem);

    matchmaker_end(index);  

    return;
}
```

The `P` function takes a semaphore, decrements its count if it's bigger than 0, or sleeps if the count is 0.

The `V` function increments the count, and wakes up a sleeping thread if there is any.

In the latter solution, each thread increments its semaphore twice because it's gonna be decremented once by each of the other two threads. Then calls `P` on each of the other two semaphores. If the count of both semaphores is greater than 0, the function continues till the end. If at least one of them has a count of 0, the thread sleeps until the count of that semaphore goes up.

What's wrong with the latter solution?

---

**Edit**

This code with semaphores works fine:

```
struct semaphore *male_sem = NULL;
struct semaphore *female_sem = NULL;
struct semaphore *matchmaker_sem = NULL;

/*
 * Called by the driver during initialization.
 */

void whalemating_init() {
    // sem_create(sem_name, sem_initial_value);
    male_sem = sem_create("male", 0);
    female_sem = sem_create("female", 0);
    matchmaker_sem = sem_create("matchmaker", 0);

}

/*
 * Called by the driver during teardown.
 */

void
whalemating_cleanup() {
    sem_destroy(male_sem);
    sem_destroy(female_sem);
    sem_destroy(matchmaker_sem);

    male_sem = NULL;
    female_sem = NULL;
    matchmaker_sem = NULL; 
}

void
male(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling male_start and male_end when
     * appropriate.
     */

    male_start(index);

    P(male_sem);
    V(matchmaker_sem);

    male_end(index);    

    return;
}

void
female(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling female_start and female_end when
     * appropriate.
     */

    female_start(index);
    
    P(female_sem);
    V(matchmaker_sem);

    female_end(index);  

    return;
}

void
matchmaker(uint32_t index)
{
    (void)index;
    /*
     * Implement this function by calling matchmaker_start and matchmaker_end
     * when appropriate.
     */

    matchmaker_start(index);

    V(male_sem);
    V(female_sem);
    P(matchmaker_sem);
    P(matchmaker_sem);

    matchmaker_end(index);  

    return;
}
```

Why does this one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: This is not directly relevant to the question but to the program logic: I think you do not need 10 threads for `matchmaker`. There should be only one thread for `matchmaker` and it should (1) wake, (2) do a match, if a free pair exists, (3) else, sleep...

Comment: @ssd Thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately that's how they've decided to test the code. I can do nothing about it.

Comment: @ssd I guess this is an assignment about synchronizing 3 threads, and the male/female/matchmaker names are just silly names. Call them Thread A, B, C if you like.

Answer (score 1):

In the working semaphore solution there never exists the situation where a matchmaker has left the semaphore access without at least one male and one female also having left behind the synchronisation code: when the matchmaker return from his second `P(matchmaker_sem)` there is guaranteed to be one male and one female past their final `V(matchmaker_sem)` so the matchmaker can do his magic.

The same can't be said of your solution:
As soon as one male has signalled his very first `V(male_sem)` and one female her `V(female_sem)` the matchmaker can run through his two necessary `P(male_sem) P(female_sem)` and exit, while the male and the female still linger inside the synchronisation code. While the total count of semaphore accesses cancels out and all female, male and matchmakers will eventually terminate, they don't do so in any synchronized way, i.e. their states do not match any intended time sequence and the synchronisation code is just an arbitrary hold-up for some of the functions. I think that the code outside of these functions stops execution of the program, not the waiting on the semaphores.

PS: if the `xy_end(index)` functions should indicate the necessary state change in the three participants, then the second code is also broken and executes just because the scheduler has only a slim chance of hitting the time window between `V(matchmaker_sem)` and `female/male_end(index)`.

PPS: maybe your misconception roots in `V(semaphore)`. This instruction does *not* block!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't quite understand the problem with the second code. Do you have any suggestion for it to not be broken? or should I not use semaphores at all in this situation?

Comment: When the scheduler puts e.g. the female in WAITING state just after this process executed `V(matchmaker_sem)` but before it could execute `female_end(index)` and sets the matchmaker to RUNNING then it depends on what you expect from the female state to be at that point, if your program is correct or not. Moving the `female_end(index)` call in front of the `V(matchmaker_sem)` won't help either as then you have in inconsistent state again. Decorating the single threads with mutual information exchange (an be it just their identity) needs more than this simple sync scheme can support.

Comment: To put it in other words: if the matchmaker is an entity opening a gate where one male an one female may pass through to mate, this matchmaker can't say without additional programming, if he opened the gate for exactly the two processes which happened to invoke the `V(matchmaker_sem)` on him before. He only knows that there are at least one male and one female waiting in front of the gate.

Comment: So it's not a good idea to use semaphores I think, right? Also I think that the code with condition variables I've provided is also broken, I suppose.. I think I should move the XX_end(id) call before I release the lock. I'm I right?